# Can I have Outlook reuse an MS Teams room from another calendar entry?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-teams

In MS Outlook's calendar, I can mark entries as MS Teams meetings. As far as I understand, this causes the following:

- A new MS Teams group chat is created.
- A link to that group chat is added to the body of the event.
- The event gets a "Join Meeting" button that directly opens the group chat in MS Teams.

Now, I am wondering whether I can reuse such a group chat across several events somehow.

The use case is as follows: We reserve a longer timespan (e.g. an entire week) for a (remote) workshop. I wish to publish that workshop "umbrella event" right away, at least to the core participants, so they know they shouldn't have any whole-day-absences during that time.

Later on, individual workshop sessions (that may or may not include additional people) are scheduled.

All of these events should be linked to the very same group chat - these workshops are typically small enough to never have any two sessions in parallel, and like this, participants can pin the group chat as a reusable item in MS Teams and enter (especially the audio chat) whenever they like, without the need to get a new link for each event (discussions in there might also take place spontaneously, aside from the aforementioned scheduled events).

**Obviously, I can copy the link from the umbrella event to the message bodies of the individual events, but can I somehow influence what group chat gets opened when the user clicks the "Join Meeting" button right in Outlook's calendar?**